# How do I find all the constants in a package using go doc?

Tags: go

I've wasted way too much time the past couple of days searching for constants like `time.Second` and `http.StatusOK` because they aren't mentioned in `go doc time` or `go doc http` respectively.

I specifically searched for a constant representing the duration 1 second by doing:

```
go doc time | grep Second
```

With no results, before reading through the entire doc page before concluding that the constant didn't exist. It was only after Googling around for about 15 minutes I happened to see `time.Second` mentioned somewhere, and when I looked it up directly (`go doc time.Second`) I found all the duration constants.

How are people supposed to find out about these constants when they're not even mentioned in the official documentation of the package? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Sorry if I missed something. But why not just go to https://godoc.org/time? It has Constants section.

Comment: @Seva That's nice for that specific package, but https://godoc.org/http doesn't exist. It's also not an option for third-party packages on Github. It seems to me like `go doc <pkg>` should list all constants, or at least provide a flag for it.

Comment: All public packages are documented on godoc.org. See for instance https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux. The standard library is at https://golang.org/pkg.

Comment: @Peter Nice, I didn't know that. It's a shame `go doc` doesn't display all the same information though. It's so much faster to type `go doc mux | less` than opening the godoc.org page in the browser.

Comment: For http package, see https://godoc.org/net/http. But I think the main issue here it that `go doc` only can find what has been documented by the author. That is it looks at documenting comments, not at the code. But if you look at time package source code you'll see that they didn't bother to add a documenting comment to every single constant as meaning of each is pretty obvious. I'd say this would be the case with other packages as well. So, if you really need it in command line, I think you need some sort of code analysis tool, not `go doc`.

Comment: @Seva Well, if you run `go doc time.Second` it displays all the `Duration` constants, so it definitely already analyzes the code.

Answer (score 2):

Start with `go doc time | grep 'const '`:

```
$ go doc time | grep 'const '
const ANSIC = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006" ...
const Nanosecond Duration = 1 ...
    const January Month = 1 + iota ...
    const Sunday Weekday = iota ...
$
```

Then `go doc time.Nanosecond`:

```
$ go doc time.Nanosecond
const (
    Nanosecond  Duration = 1
    Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
    Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
    Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
    Minute               = 60 * Second
    Hour                 = 60 * Minute
)
    Common durations. There is no definition for units of Day or larger to avoid
    confusion across daylight savings time zone transitions.

    To count the number of units in a Duration, divide:

    second := time.Second
    fmt.Print(int64(second/time.Millisecond)) // prints 1000

    To convert an integer number of units to a Duration, multiply:

    seconds := 10
    fmt.Print(time.Duration(seconds)*time.Second) // prints 10s

$
```

---

Start with `go doc http | grep 'const '`:

```
$ go doc http | grep 'const '
const MethodGet = "GET" ...
const StatusContinue = 100 ...
const DefaultMaxHeaderBytes = 1 << 20
const DefaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost = 2
const TimeFormat = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 GMT"
const TrailerPrefix = "Trailer:"
    const StateNew ConnState = iota ...
$
```

Then `go doc http.StatusContinue`:

```
$ go doc http.StatusContinue

package http // import "net/http"

const (
    StatusContinue           = 100 // RFC 7231, 6.2.1
    StatusSwitchingProtocols = 101 // RFC 7231, 6.2.2
    StatusProcessing         = 102 // RFC 2518, 10.1

    StatusOK                   = 200 // RFC 7231, 6.3.1
    StatusCreated              = 201 // RFC 7231, 6.3.2
    StatusAccepted             = 202 // RFC 7231, 6.3.3
    StatusNonAuthoritativeInfo = 203 // RFC 7231, 6.3.4
    StatusNoContent            = 204 // RFC 7231, 6.3.5
    StatusResetContent         = 205 // RFC 7231, 6.3.6
    StatusPartialContent       = 206 // RFC 7233, 4.1
    StatusMultiStatus          = 207 // RFC 4918, 11.1
    StatusAlreadyReported      = 208 // RFC 5842, 7.1
    StatusIMUsed               = 226 // RFC 3229, 10.4.1

    StatusMultipleChoices  = 300 // RFC 7231, 6.4.1
    StatusMovedPermanently = 301 // RFC 7231, 6.4.2
    StatusFound            = 302 // RFC 7231, 6.4.3
    StatusSeeOther         = 303 // RFC 7231, 6.4.4
    StatusNotModified      = 304 // RFC 7232, 4.1
    StatusUseProxy         = 305 // RFC 7231, 6.4.5

    StatusTemporaryRedirect = 307 // RFC 7231, 6.4.7
    StatusPermanentRedirect = 308 // RFC 7538, 3

    StatusBadRequest                   = 400 // RFC 7231, 6.5.1
    StatusUnauthorized                 = 401 // RFC 7235, 3.1
    StatusPaymentRequired              = 402 // RFC 7231, 6.5.2
    StatusForbidden                    = 403 // RFC 7231, 6.5.3
    StatusNotFound                     = 404 // RFC 7231, 6.5.4
    StatusMethodNotAllowed             = 405 // RFC 7231, 6.5.5
    StatusNotAcceptable                = 406 // RFC 7231, 6.5.6
    StatusProxyAuthRequired            = 407 // RFC 7235, 3.2
    StatusRequestTimeout               = 408 // RFC 7231, 6.5.7
    StatusConflict                     = 409 // RFC 7231, 6.5.8
    StatusGone                         = 410 // RFC 7231, 6.5.9
    StatusLengthRequired               = 411 // RFC 7231, 6.5.10
    StatusPreconditionFailed           = 412 // RFC 7232, 4.2
    StatusRequestEntityTooLarge        = 413 // RFC 7231, 6.5.11
    StatusRequestURITooLong            = 414 // RFC 7231, 6.5.12
    StatusUnsupportedMediaType         = 415 // RFC 7231, 6.5.13
    StatusRequestedRangeNotSatisfiable = 416 // RFC 7233, 4.4
    StatusExpectationFailed            = 417 // RFC 7231, 6.5.14
    StatusTeapot                       = 418 // RFC 7168, 2.3.3
    StatusMisdirectedRequest           = 421 // RFC 7540, 9.1.2
    StatusUnprocessableEntity          = 422 // RFC 4918, 11.2
    StatusLocked                       = 423 // RFC 4918, 11.3
    StatusFailedDependency             = 424 // RFC 4918, 11.4
    StatusUpgradeRequired              = 426 // RFC 7231, 6.5.15
    StatusPreconditionRequired         = 428 // RFC 6585, 3
    StatusTooManyRequests              = 429 // RFC 6585, 4
    StatusRequestHeaderFieldsTooLarge  = 431 // RFC 6585, 5
    StatusUnavailableForLegalReasons   = 451 // RFC 7725, 3

    StatusInternalServerError           = 500 // RFC 7231, 6.6.1
    StatusNotImplemented                = 501 // RFC 7231, 6.6.2
    StatusBadGateway                    = 502 // RFC 7231, 6.6.3
    StatusServiceUnavailable            = 503 // RFC 7231, 6.6.4
    StatusGatewayTimeout                = 504 // RFC 7231, 6.6.5
    StatusHTTPVersionNotSupported       = 505 // RFC 7231, 6.6.6
    StatusVariantAlsoNegotiates         = 506 // RFC 2295, 8.1
    StatusInsufficientStorage           = 507 // RFC 4918, 11.5
    StatusLoopDetected                  = 508 // RFC 5842, 7.2
    StatusNotExtended                   = 510 // RFC 2774, 7
    StatusNetworkAuthenticationRequired = 511 // RFC 6585, 6
)
    HTTP status codes as registered with IANA. See:
    https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml
$
```

Comment: I did actually `go doc time.Duration`, but the constants aren't mentioned there either, so I'm not sure what you're saying :P Did you mean `go doc time.Nanosecond`? That produces a list of all `Duration` constants, but it's very unintuitive.

Comment: @Hubro: See my revised answer.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at  `go tool api time`.

Comment: @Seva That sounds really useful, but for some reason, I don't have that tool: `go tool: no such tool "api"`. This probably merits its own question, but do you have any idea why? Google is giving me nothing on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, took me some time to realize it. Actually, we're looking at a wrong command line tool. Use `godoc time` instead.

If you don't have it, you can install it as follows:

```
$ go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
$ go build golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

Then copy it to your path (or run from where it is).

Comment: Neat, all the info from godoc.org, but with a quick console command

Answer (score 0):

Just run `go doc` with the flag `-all` to display the full documentation for a package including its constants:

```
Flags:
        -all
                Show all the documentation for the package.
```

Source: `go help doc`

You can then filter the output i.e. with `sed` to include only the constants.

Here are some constants from the [http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) package:

```
$ go doc -all http | sed -n '/^const (/,/^)/p'
const (
        MethodGet     = "GET"
        MethodHead    = "HEAD"
        MethodPost    = "POST"
        MethodPut     = "PUT"
        MethodPatch   = "PATCH" // RFC 5789
        MethodDelete  = "DELETE"
        MethodConnect = "CONNECT"
        MethodOptions = "OPTIONS"
        MethodTrace   = "TRACE"
)
const (
        StatusContinue           = 100 // RFC 9110, 15.2.1
        StatusSwitchingProtocols = 101 // RFC 9110, 15.2.2
        StatusProcessing         = 102 // RFC 2518, 10.1
        StatusEarlyHints         = 103 // RFC 8297

        StatusOK                   = 200 // RFC 9110, 15.3.1
        StatusCreated              = 201 // RFC 9110, 15.3.2
        StatusAccepted             = 202 // RFC 9110, 15.3.3
...
```

The same for the [time](https://pkg.go.dev/time) package:

```
$ go doc -all time | sed -n '/^const (/,/^)/p'
const (
        Layout      = "01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700" // The reference time, in numerical order.
        ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
        UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
        RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
        RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
        RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
        RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
        RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
        RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
        Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
        // Handy time stamps.
        Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
        StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
        StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
        StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
        DateTime   = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
        DateOnly   = "2006-01-02"
        TimeOnly   = "15:04:05"
)
const (
        Nanosecond  Duration = 1
        Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
        Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
        Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
        Minute               = 60 * Second
        Hour                 = 60 * Minute
)
const (
        January Month = 1 + iota
        February
        March
        April
        May
        June
        July
        August
        September
...
```

The online package documentation on https://pkg.go.dev/ includes "Constants" sections as well.